# Handling datas from dynamically generated form

Tags: php, jquery, dynamicform

I thought of making something that generates lots of form dynamically and then using jquery to handle their submission.

So i generate the form using php by using something like this.

```
while(some condition) {
    echo "<form method=post action=specific_url.php name=some_form_name>";
    echo "<input type=text>";
    echo "<input type=submit>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

Well the above is just a skeleton. The main Problem is how should i name/id the form elements so that i can uniquely identify each form during submission and submit them, and use can extract the data at the specific_url page without any problem.

A direct analogy of this feature that i can think at the top of my head is that of facebook posts, where each post has got a comment box.

UPDATE

I guess i wasn't very clear with the question. Sorry about that. Let me rephrase it.

So till now, I have these dynamically generated forms. Now suppose user writes in one of the textbox and click on submit button.

At these point jquery should take control of it. Send that particular form data to the url. Retrieve the result and do something.

So in the end, I should be able to do something like this

```
$(some_selector).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('specific_url.php',$(some_selector).serialize(),function(data) {
        // some stuff
    });
});
```

Here "some_selector" is that selector which gets activated when a particular form is submitted and then sending that form's data.

Comment: Well if you follow the FB comment logic, the form is attached to a post. The post itself most certainly already has an idea so the comment form can use this id. You could use the post’s id to prefix your form's id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hidden form element and set its value to an id for the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1">
```

This way you can access the form_id like any other form value once you submit it. I am looking at the facebook source now and I see a few hidden form elements next to the comment boxes

Comment: you probably won't find any. I doubt you'll even find a <form> tag. Fb uses much more clever implementations: hidden field are old but simple.

Comment: Like I said, I already found a few hidden form elements on facebook. I'm looking at them now. Not even facebook is too fancy for hidden form elements

Comment: oh, I just fond a <form> tag too... I guess they'll have plenty of time to spare, blocking default form behaviour and prevent page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

It is a requirement that the element id attribute is unique, not so with the name attribute.

It is also possible to use arrays of elements, for example :

```
<input name="comment[]" type=text>
<input name="comment[]" type=text>
<input name="comment[]" type=text>.
```

In your PHP. the value of $_POST['comment'] will be send as an array.

If you want to uniquely identify each comment in your PHP code, you will be forced to rename them uniquely.

```
<input name="comment1" type=text>
<input name="comment2" type=text>
<input name="comment3" type=text>
```

Since you are generating the form using PHP, this would be easy to keep track of the name that should be generated.

If you have multiple forms, you have free reign, sort of. There is no need a name for the form. However, to identify where in the page the form is places, place a hidden field.

```
while(some condition) {
    echo "<form method=post action=specific_url.php";
    echo "<input name='position_in_page' type='hidden' value='$somevalue'>";
    echo "<input name='comment' type='text'>";
    echo "<input type='submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```